# .hover doesn't work when hovered with draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Please pardon me for my bad english...

situation:
I've got a menu with submenus. 
The submenus open when hovered. 
(simple dropdown menu with ul's and li's)

I've got a admin area from which i want to drag something in the menu.

problem:
When I drag something into the menu, it won't collapse, as if the .hover doesn't work
Also the menu is sortable, because of the same problem you can drag subitems to mainmenu, but items from mainmenu can't be dragged to the subitems, because .hover doesn't work and the menu won't collapse.

Is .hover ignored when you drag something onto it?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided some code.

Comment: I think you should use 'mousein' and 'mouseout' events instead of hover. There are many parameters cause hover doesn't work. show a sample code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the

```
.hover(function(){},function(){});
```

with

```
.live('hover',function(){});
```